# Full screen webpage

Tags: safari, fullscreen

I'm trying to make my webpage fullscreen. I've made it work on Chrome, but for some reason it wont work on safari. Anyone know why?

```
  <img onclick="launchFullscreen(document.documentElement);" src="http://e-daktik.dk/ranger.gif" alt="">
  <script>
  // Find the right method, call on correct element
  function launchFullscreen(element) {
    if(element.requestFullscreen) {
      element.requestFullscreen();
    } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
      element.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to try and have the user simulate this themselves (by clicking F11 or any other key for their specific browser) **because this will only work with Google Chrome and Internet Explorer.** You should have a message saying to click F11 or something if you really need your webpage to be full screen. I hope this helped you.